# Trying to clear a textEdit box in QT C++ (using QT Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, textedit

I'm new to QT, young at programming, and not understanding all the help materials for the classes in QT.

I have the following code, which executes on a button click, inserting text. This works fine but I want to clear the textEdit first, then insert the new text. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Any help is much appreciated.

```
QTextCharFormat textFormat;
QTextCursor cursor(ui->textEdit->textCursor());
cursor.insertText("<some text to insert", textFormat);
```

It appears that I have to use setPosition() and movePosition() to select the text, then removeSelectedText() to clear it. I don't know how to determine the first and last positions in the document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QTextEdit has a clear function, which deletes all text.  In the documentation it's listed as a Slot.

[QTextEdit::clear()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#clear)

Comment: I tried using it like this to no avail. Probably me not understanding the usage but it has worked with other things. 

QTextEdit clear(ui->textEdit);

I also tried with selectAll() before. No dice. John, I'm evidently missing knowledge I need here. Do you have any quick answers?

Comment: Got it! 

ui->textEdit->clear();

That did the trick! Thanks!